# JSHint tolerate braceless If Statements

Tags: jshint

Is there a flag to allow braceless If statements in JSHINT?

ie:

`if (true) return false;`

I've looked through the docs, but didn't find anything...

Answer (score 1):

Never mind, found the solution:

`curly: false`

http://www.jshint.com/docs/options/#curly